# sbcl common lisp step-into doesn't work as expected?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

atm using lem editor with sbcl compiler for common lisp and step-into doesn't work as expected. rather than stepping into, it just resumes the execution.

I'm calling step and used `(declaim (optimize (debug 3)))`, which made the debugger step over a few more things, but I'm still not able to step into functions.

```
(step
  (setf (nth 12 (pieces (chessboard new-game)))
  (calculate-ray-moves
    (nth 12 (pieces (chessboard new-game))))))
```

[image]

here's the function I'm trying to step into, feedbacks on my code are welcomed.
[image]

Comment: Just poking around, but what you show is a method specializing on a class `piece-with-ray-attack`, while the debugger prints the argument as `Q` — have you defined a `print-object` method for your pieces, or is this just a string or character?  Are you sure that the method is found correctly, i. e. executed at all?  Are you sure that you compiled the _generic function_ as well as the method with the debug settings to instrument it for single stepping?

Comment: @Svante yeah, Q is how the piece is represented, so it's the piece object I'm passing to the function. The method is found, it is actually called, and it outputs the expected value correctly when executing it on the REPL, I compiled everything, but do I need to add debug settings for each method? As in, (defun (debug 3)) or something like that.

Comment: Without enough code to reproduce what is happening there is essentially no way anybody but you can can answer this question.  Further, the incomplete fragment of your code that you have included is an *picture*, not the actual code, which makes it all but useless: nobody is going to type in the code from a picture of it.  So (a) please provide a minimum reproducable example, and (b) do not post pictures of code, post code.